# Opencart 2.2.0 enable search by manufacturer

Tags: php, mysql, opencart

I am using OC 2.2.0 and been struggling with the following problem for a while now:

Example: I enter Siemens in header search and click SHOW ALL RESULTS, my search page appears with all results. The problem is - results list includes only products that have Siemens in their NAME. What I need is to show **all** **products  in search results list, belonging to that manufacturer**, which in our example is Siemens manufacturer. In my `search.php` controller file, results are defined in this line:

```
$results = $this->model_catalog_product->getProducts($filter_data);
```

Which shows me that  `getProducts($filter_data)` function of product.php file in model-catalog-product is where I need to define results. I tried tweaking the query in this function so that it includes manufacturer in search results too, but with no luck. So far, my `getProducts($filter_data)` function looks like this:

```
public function getProducts($data = array()) {
        $sql = "SELECT p.product_id, (SELECT AVG(rating) AS total FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "review r1 WHERE r1.product_id = p.product_id AND r1.status = '1' GROUP BY r1.product_id) AS rating, (SELECT price FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_discount pd2 WHERE pd2.product_id = p.product_id AND pd2.customer_group_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_customer_group_id') . "' AND pd2.quantity = '1' AND ((pd2.date_start = '0000-00-00' OR pd2.date_start < NOW()) AND (pd2.date_end = '0000-00-00' OR pd2.date_end > NOW())) ORDER BY pd2.priority ASC, pd2.price ASC LIMIT 1) AS discount, (SELECT price FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_special ps WHERE ps.product_id = p.product_id AND ps.customer_group_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_customer_group_id') . "' AND ((ps.date_start = '0000-00-00' OR ps.date_start < NOW()) AND (ps.date_end = '0000-00-00' OR ps.date_end > NOW())) ORDER BY ps.priority ASC, ps.price ASC LIMIT 1) AS special";

        if (!empty($data['filter_category_id'])) {
            if (!empty($data['filter_sub_category'])) {
                if(!empty($data['filter_sub_subcategory'])) {
                    $sql .= " FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_to_category p2c";
                } else {
                    $sql .= " FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_to_category p2c";
                }
                //$sql .= " FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "category_path cp LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product_to_category p2c ON (cp.category_id = p2c.category_id)";
            } else {
                $sql .= " FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_to_category p2c LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "category cc ON (p2c.category_id = cc.category_id)";
            }

            if (!empty($data['filter_filter'])) {
                $sql .= " LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product_filter pf ON (p2c.product_id = pf.product_id) LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product p ON (pf.product_id = p.product_id)";
            } else {
                $sql .= " LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product p ON (p2c.product_id = p.product_id)";
            }
        } else {
            $sql .= " FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product p";
        }

        $sql .= " LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product_description pd ON (p.product_id = pd.product_id) LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product_to_store p2s ON (p.product_id = p2s.product_id) WHERE pd.language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "' AND p.status = '1' AND p.date_available <= NOW() AND p2s.store_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_store_id') . "'";

        if (!empty($data['filter_category_id'])) {

            if (!empty($data['filter_sub_category'])) {
                if(!empty($data['filter_sub_subcategory'])) {
                    $sql .= " AND p2c.category_id = '" . (int)$data['filter_sub_subcategory'] . "'";
                } else {
                    $sql .= " AND p2c.category_id = '" . (int)$data['filter_sub_category'] . "'";
                }
                //$sql .= " AND cp.path_id = '" . (int)$data['filter_category_id'] . "'";
            } else {
                $sql .= " AND cc.parent_id = '" . (int)$data['filter_category_id'] . "'";
            }

            if (!empty($data['filter_filter'])) {
                $implode = array();

                $filters = explode(',', $data['filter_filter']);

                foreach ($filters as $filter_id) {
                    $implode[] = (int)$filter_id;
                }

                $sql .= " AND pf.filter_id IN (" . implode(',', $implode) . ")";
            }
        }

        if (!empty($data['filter_subcategory_id'])) {
            if (!empty($data['filter_sub_category'])) {
                $sql .= " AND p2c.category_id = '" . (int)$data['filter_sub_category'] . "'";
                //$sql .= " AND cp.path_id = '" . (int)$data['filter_category_id'] . "'";
            } else {
                $sql .= " AND p2c.category_id = '" . (int)$data['filter_category_id'] . "'";
            }

            if (!empty($data['filter_filter'])) {
                $implode = array();

                $filters = explode(',', $data['filter_filter']);

                foreach ($filters as $filter_id) {
                    $implode[] = (int)$filter_id;
                }

                $sql .= " AND pf.filter_id IN (" . implode(',', $implode) . ")";
            }
        }

        if (!empty($data['filter_sub_subcategory'])) {
            if (!empty($data['filter_sub_subcategory'])) {
                $sql .= " AND p2c.category_id = '" . (int)$data['filter_sub_subcategory'] . "'";
                //$sql .= " AND cp.path_id = '" . (int)$data['filter_category_id'] . "'";
            } else {
                $sql .= " AND p2c.category_id = '" . (int)$data['filter_category_id'] . "'";
            }

            if (!empty($data['filter_filter'])) {
                $implode = array();

                $filters = explode(',', $data['filter_filter']);

                foreach ($filters as $filter_id) {
                    $implode[] = (int)$filter_id;
                }

                $sql .= " AND pf.filter_id IN (" . implode(',', $implode) . ")";
            }
        }

        if (!empty($data['filter_name']) || !empty($data['filter_tag'])) {
            $sql .= " AND (";

            if (!empty($data['filter_name'])) {
                $implode = array();

                $words = explode(' ', trim(preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $data['filter_name'])));

                foreach ($words as $word) {
                    $implode[] = "pd.name LIKE '%" . $this->db->escape($word) . "%'";
                }

                if ($implode) {
                    $sql .= " " . implode(" AND ", $implode) . "";
                }

                if (!empty($data['filter_description'])) {
                    $sql .= " OR pd.description LIKE '%" . $this->db->escape($data['filter_name']) . "%'";
                }
            }

            if (!empty($data['filter_name']) && !empty($data['filter_tag'])) {
                $sql .= " OR ";
            }

            if (!empty($data['filter_tag'])) {
                $sql .= "pd.tag LIKE '%" . $this->db->escape($data['filter_tag']) . "%'";
            }

            if (!empty($data['filter_name'])) {
                $sql .= " OR LCASE(p.model) = '" . $this->db->escape(utf8_strtolower($data['filter_name'])) . "'";
                $sql .= " OR LCASE(p.sku) = '" . $this->db->escape(utf8_strtolower($data['filter_name'])) . "'";
                $sql .= " OR LCASE(p.upc) = '" . $this->db->escape(utf8_strtolower($data['filter_name'])) . "'";
                $sql .= " OR LCASE(p.ean) = '" . $this->db->escape(utf8_strtolower($data['filter_name'])) . "'";
                $sql .= " OR LCASE(p.wholesale) = '" . $this->db->escape(utf8_strtolower($data['filter_name'])) . "'";
                $sql .= " OR LCASE(p.isbn) = '" . $this->db->escape(utf8_strtolower($data['filter_name'])) . "'";
                $sql .= " OR LCASE(p.mpn) = '" . $this->db->escape(utf8_strtolower($data['filter_name'])) . "'";
            }

            $sql .= ")";
        }

        if (!empty($data['filter_manufacturer_id'])) {
            $sql .= " AND p.manufacturer_id = '".(int)$data['filter_manufacturer_id']."'";
        }


        $sql .= " GROUP BY p.product_id";

        $sort_data = array(
            'pd.name',
            'p.model',
            'p.quantity',
            'p.price',
            'rating',
            'p.sort_order',
            'p.date_added'
        );

        if (isset($data['sort']) && in_array($data['sort'], $sort_data)) {
            if ($data['sort'] == 'pd.name' || $data['sort'] == 'p.model') {
                $sql .= " ORDER BY LCASE(" . $data['sort'] . ")";
            } elseif ($data['sort'] == 'p.price') {
                $sql .= " ORDER BY (CASE WHEN special IS NOT NULL THEN special WHEN discount IS NOT NULL THEN discount ELSE p.price END)";
            } else {
                $sql .= " ORDER BY " . $data['sort'];
            }
        } else {
            $sql .= " ORDER BY p.sort_order";
        }

        if (isset($data['order']) && ($data['order'] == 'DESC')) {
            $sql .= " DESC, LCASE(pd.name) DESC";
        } else {
            $sql .= " ASC, LCASE(pd.name) ASC";
        }

        if (isset($data['start']) || isset($data['limit'])) {
            if ($data['start'] < 0) {
                $data['start'] = 0;
            }

            if ($data['limit'] < 1) {
                $data['limit'] = 20;
            }

            $sql .= " LIMIT " . (int)$data['start'] . "," . (int)$data['limit'];
        }

        $product_data = array();

        $query = $this->db->query($sql);

        foreach ($query->rows as $result) {
            $product_data[$result['product_id']] = $this->getProduct($result['product_id']);
        }

        return $product_data;
    }
```

Can anyone help tweak the query so that it can show **all** products belonging to a searched manufacturer?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, finally i realized what was the missing query. Before the line

```
 $sql .= " LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product_description pd ON
 (p.product_id = pd.product_id) LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX .
 "product_to_store p2s
```

I had to put `$sql .= " LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "manufacturer m ON (m.manufacturer_id = p.manufacturer_id) ";`

And then just  before the line

```
$sql .= " OR LCASE(p.model) = '" . $this->db->escape(utf8_strtolower($data['filter_name'])) . "'";
```

I had to put

```
         $sql .= " OR LCASE(m.name) = '" . $this->db->escape(utf8_strtolower($data['filter_name'])) . "'";
```

So obviously I was missing the manufacturer data. This way I pulled the data from manufacturer table and processed it correctly. I hope this helps someone, cheers!

Comment: Many thanks for this hint! It still works in Opencart 3.0.3.2
There is a small typo in your last code line, though, it's missing a >: instead of “db-escape” it should be “db->escape”

Comment: You are welcome, I am glad you find it helpful. I corrected the code, thanx for pointing it out.