# Search product by manufacturer on Opencart 2.3.0.2

Tags: opencart

I would like to search for products by the manufacturer on Opencart 2.3.0.2.

On `catalog/model/catalog/product.php`

Before

```
$sql .= " LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product_description pd ON (p.product_id = pd.product_id)
```

I put this code:

```
 $sql .= " LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "manufacturer m ON (m.manufacturer_id = p.manufacturer_id) ";
```

and Before the line:

```
$sql .= " OR LCASE(p.model) = '" . $this->db->escape(utf8_strtolower($data['filter_name'])) . "'";
```

I put this code

```
 $sql .= " ORDER BY p.quantity<1, LCASE(" . $data['sort'] . ")";
```

But it shows me:

> Unknown: Object of class DB could not be converted to string on
>   catalog\model\catalog\product.php

How can i search name on table manufacturer and shows to my customers products by manufacturer

Comment: Can you send the full error. there should be a line number that should help. also please paste the full code of the modification so that we can see how exactly you have edited the original code.

Comment: I found the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44798504/opencart-2-2-0-enable-search-by-manufacturer   Tks

Answer (score 0):

**Try this code it will help you**

your last order by code is wrong - remove this

```
 $sql .= " ORDER BY p.quantity<1, LCASE(" . $data['sort'] . ")";
```

Do this below

before

```
$sql .= " GROUP BY p.product_id";
```

put this code

```
  $sql .= " AND p.quantity > 0";
```

You have to comment this code for More then Zero quantity

```
     /* comment this code 
       if (isset($data['sort']) && in_array($data['sort'], $sort_data)) {
            if ($data['sort'] == 'pd.name' || $data['sort'] == 'p.model') {
                $sql .= " ORDER BY LCASE(" . $data['sort'] . ")";
            } elseif ($data['sort'] == 'p.price') {
                $sql .= " ORDER BY (CASE WHEN special IS NOT NULL THEN special WHEN discount IS NOT NULL THEN discount ELSE p.price END)";
            } else {
                $sql .= " ORDER BY " . $data['sort'];
            }
        } else {
            $sql .= " ORDER BY p.sort_order";
        }
    */
```

and add this

```
   if (isset($data['sort']) && in_array($data['sort'], $sort_data)) {
        if ($data['sort'] == 'pd.name' || $data['sort'] == 'p.model') {
            $sql .= " ORDER BY p.quantity, LCASE(" . $data['sort'] . ")";
        } elseif ($data['sort'] == 'p.price') {
            $sql .= " ORDER BY (CASE WHEN special IS NOT NULL THEN special WHEN discount IS NOT NULL THEN discount ELSE p.price END)";
        } else {
            $sql .= " ORDER BY p.quantity, " . $data['sort'];
        }
    } else {
        $sql .= " ORDER BY p.quantity, p.sort_order";
    }
```

[image: Search product by manufacturer]

Comment: I found the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44798504/opencart-2-2-0-enable-search-by-manufacturer